# How to run the SFML template?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, templates, sfml

I have installed the SFML templates (SFML App and SFML CLT) for Xcode to learn more about the library and improve my c++ skills. But I get an Error when I'm trying to run the template.

I have already installed the SFML framework and some external libraries, which SFML depends on.

But when I choose the template "SFML App" to create a new project and I try to run it, I get this error:

```
ditto: can't get real path for source '/Users/SFML/Desktop/packaging/tmp/install/Library/Frameworks/sfml-system.framework'
couldn't copy /Users/SFML/Desktop/packaging/tmp/install/Library/Frameworks/sfml-system.framework to /Users/seadkurtovic/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/My_First_SFML_App-bcabgonrxpifggalnkqaxhpyqygs/Build/Products/Debug/My First SFML App.app/Contents/Frameworks//sfml-system.framework
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

Does anyone know what I did wrong? Because I have actually followed everything carefully according to this tutorial: [SFML and Xcode (macOS)](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/start-osx.php)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't get real path for source - Xcode, SFML, C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53325026/cant-get-real-path-for-source-xcode-sfml-c)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem! And I found the answer here:
https://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=24677.0

Build phases -> Run script -> check "Run script only when installing"

Here is the image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KUwj.jpg

Comment: This will essentially delay the problem so that it only appears when running Product > Archive, rather than appearing during development and debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, did you try installing the command line tools for XCode?

Try run this code inside the terminal:

```
xcode-select --install
```

Comment: When I enter this command, I get this message:  `xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates`. So yes, I've already installed the command line tools for XCode.